# How to give alternating table rows specific background colors using php laravel

Tags: laravel-5

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tmp</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $row)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$row->temp}}</td>
                    </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Above Example, if the temp value greater than 40, what is the easiest and best way give a specific color for Temp

Comment: Create a css class, then as you said, if `$row->temp` > 40 apply that class to the opening `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

```
   @if($row->temp>'40')
    <td bgcolor="#dd2c00">{{$row->temp}}</td>
    @endif
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Then why asked this question?

Comment: Previously I tried with JS & CSS, I think that's the easiest way